# One child process per for loop in make?

Tags: makefile, child-process

Let me first write a quick Makefile as a showcase:

```
#!/bin/make -f

folders := $(shell find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print)

make_dir:
    @mkdir -p "test0"

pwd_test:
    @cd "test0" && pwd
    @pwd

pwd_all:
    @for f in $(folders); do \
        cd "$${f}" && pwd; \
        pwd; \
        cd ..; \
    done
```

First do `make make_dir` and then see the different results:

```
➜  so  make pwd_test
/data/cache/tmp/so/test0
/data/cache/tmp/so
➜  so  make pwd_all 
/data/cache/tmp/so/test0
/data/cache/tmp/so/test0
```

You see that in the for loop it is necessary to do `cd ..`. Apparently, now there is no child process spawn for the `cd X && pwd` command, while that is normally the case. Is this behaviour specific to make or specific to my shell?

Comment: Short answer (thanks to below): the **for loop** is part of the shell you use. So make does not have a clue about **for loops**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make spawns a new process for each command in the rule. Since the for loop is one command you get only one process.

Take a look at [Recipe Execution](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Execution)

**Edit:**

Each line in a makefile gets it own subshell. Commands that have
`\` tells make that the next line should be part of the current line.

The reason the for loop get its own subshell is because make see the line as

```
@for f in $(folders); do cd "$${f}" && pwd; pwd; cd ..; done
```

MadScientist explains it fairly well. Any command that you can type in your
shell in one line will be executed by make in one subshell or process.

If you were to run this in ksh, ksh would be passed 
`for f in $(folders); do cd "$${f}" && pwd; pwd; cd ..; done` and it would be
run in that one subshell. If ksh did not have a for loop implemented this
probably would error and make would say the command returned some error code.

---

Explanation of pwd_test

```
pwd_test:
    @cd "test0" && pwd
    @pwd
```

`@cd "test0" && pwd` is seen as one line so the subshell updates its current
working directory and then prints out what the current working is.

`@pwd` At this line make spawns a new subshell that contains the old working
directory (or the directory make was called form) and `pwd` prints that
directory.

Comment: Put another way, if you cut and pasted that command including backslashes into your shell, you'd get exactly the same behavior as you see with make.  Make takes each logical line of the recipe and sends it to a shell.  What the shell does with it, make has no idea.  It just waits for the shell to finish and looks at the exit code.

Comment: so the **for loop** is a shell command itself, if there would not be a **for loop** defined for a given shell (say a lightweight version of the Korn shell ksd), **make** (run in that shell) will not have a **for loop** implementation?

Comment: I think I understand. Make does not need to use for-loops! The make-way to do things is namely by defining targets:
`pwd_make_all: $(folders)

.PHONY: $(folders)
$(folders):
 @cd $@ && pwd`

Comment: I just didn't realize that make is using shell functionality to have **for** and **while** loops.

It's possible to use a one-liner with an explicit subshell evocation: `@for f in $(folders); do ( cd "$${f}" && pwd ); pwd; done`. It just wasn't clear to me that make had this "parasitic" or "smart" behavior. Make actually has no **for loop**!